# Solid White background-color

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm fairly new to HTML/CSS, and am developing a very simple website with a white menu bar on the top (it looks better than it sounds). However, unfortunately the menu bar background is transparent - text seems to appear within the menu bar as I scroll down in the page. How do I make a white background non-transparent?

Comment: apply `background: white;` to the menu. If you want help with your code, post the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that by declaring background color as white.

Example:

```
<style>

#menu-id{
      background-color: white;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, I will recommend a few things.

- set `background: white;`
- set `opacity: 1.0;`

That should do the trick.  Please post your code if you are still having problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>#menuid{background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);}</style>
```

```css
<style>#menuid {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use background color just like following example, change `.box` background color `#fff` to get the white color.

```css
.box {
  width:100%;
  background:#eee; /*background:#fff; use here white background */
}
.box ul {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  list-style:none;
}
.box ul li {
  display:inline-block;
}
.box ul li a {
  display:block;
  padding:5px;
  margin:1px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.box ul li a:hover {
  background:#ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```